# Summing up values in custom attr loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a loop which generates `<li>` with custom attribute `filesize`, now I want to search all `<li>` with this class and sum the value, but instead it returns two values next to each other and not summing the values.

https://jsfiddle.net/y6yLL0yv/1/

```
var myElements = jQuery(".fileRess");
var sumoffilessize = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    var valueofthis = myElements.eq(i).attr("sizefile");
    var valuetostr = valueofthis.toString();
    var sumoffilessize = (valuetostr + sumoffilessize);
}

alert(sumoffilessize);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fileInfo1">
    <div style="clear:both;padding:5px;" class="fileRess" sizefile="206519" id="fileres_0">
        <input size="1" type="file" class="file" name="attach[]" id="attacher" style="display:none" multiple="" value="undefined">206519 </div>
    <div style="clear:both;padding:5px;" class="fileRess" sizefile="290284" id="fileres_1">
        <input size="1" type="file" class="file" name="attach[]" id="attacher" style="display:none" multiple="" value="undefined">290284 </div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Convert the value read from [DOM(**string**) to Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert the string that you got from `sizefile attribute` to a number by using `parseInt(numberString)` before doing summation of it,

```
var myElements = jQuery(".fileRess");
var sumoffilessize = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
  sumoffilessize += parseInt(myElements.eq(i).attr("sizefile")
}

alert(sumoffilessize);
```

If you do not convert it, then `string concatenation` will be happened since `+` is common for string concatenation and for mathematical addition. It will do string concatenation when it meets a single `string operand`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/y6yLL0yv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The value read from the DOM is the **string**. And `+` will work as string concatenation operator if any of the operands is string.

The string need to be converted to Number when read from DOM and then perform arithmetic operations on it.

There are many options to convert string to number. See [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

```js
var total = 0;

// Iterate over all the elements having the `fileRess` class
$('.fileRess').each(function () {
    // Get the attribute value from DOM
    // Cast to Number by using unary `+` operator
    // Add to the `total` variable
    total += +$(this).attr('sizefile');
});

$('#result').text('Total: ' + total);
```

```css
#result {
  margin: 10px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fileInfo1">
    <div style="clear:both;padding:5px;" class="fileRess" sizefile="206519" id="fileres_0">
        <input size="1" type="file" class="file" name="attach[]" id="attacher" style="display:none" multiple="" value="undefined">206519 </div>
    <div style="clear:both;padding:5px;" class="fileRess" sizefile="290284" id="fileres_1">
        <input size="1" type="file" class="file" name="attach[]" id="attacher" style="display:none" multiple="" value="undefined">290284 </div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

```
var total = 0;

// Iterate over all the elements having the `fileRess` class
$('.fileRess').each(function () {
    // Get the attribute value from DOM
    // Cast to Number by using unary `+` operator
    // Add to the `total` variable
    total += +$(this).attr('sizefile');
});
console.log(total);
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/y6yLL0yv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace

```
var valuetostr = valueofthis.toString();
```

with

```
var valuetostr = parseInt(valueofthis.toString());
```